# How would you translate "but still" into German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, modal-particle

> Es gab keinen Kaffee mehr, aber noch fragte er nach einer Tasse.
>
> ***There was no more coffee, but still he asked for another cup.***

Does ***aber noch*** fit the context?

Comment: Your German sentence says that "he asked a cup."

Comment: no the sentence is correct. Tasse is related to Kaffee here.

Comment: Ich würde vorschlagen, "asked for" eher mit "bat um" als "fragte nach" zu übersetzen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nearly. You might like to use:

```
Es gab keinen Kaffee mehr, aber dennoch fragte er nach einer Tasse [Kaffee].
```

`trotzdem` would also do instead of [`dennoch`](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dennoch).

Also please note that the `aber`  ist optional.

Comment: Perhaps someone who knows how to do this might like to add the Lautschrift for `dennoch`?

Comment: The IPA? [ˈdɛnɔχ]

Comment: Compare http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dennoch

Answer (score 3):

I would translate it like this:

*Es gab keinen Kaffee mehr, aber dennoch bat er um eine weitere Tasse.*

Answer (score 2):

> Obschon der Kaffee bereits zur Neige gegangen war, konnte er sich der
>   Verlautbarung seines Verlangens nach einer weiteren Tasse nicht
>   entbrechen.

Well, you'll have the undivided attention of the assembly.

But you'll want to use instead:

> Obwohl kein Kaffee mehr da war, bat er um eine weitere Tasse.

Comment: Bayeux meme much? :)